# Arguments vs Options in Apache CLI

Tags: apache, command-line-interface

I am trying to use Apache CLI for one of my applications which has required arguments and also options. For the required arguments, I do not want to have any options specifier ( no hyphens). So the I am looking for something like this

```
application requiredArgument, -opt1 optionalArg1, -opt2 optionalArg2
```

Is there any way this can be accomplished? Or are there any other parsers that can be used?